# SQL 2008 R2 p2p replication alternate

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication, database-replication

***The requirement.*** Establish 3 global data centers (sites) and direct users to their closest site based on a Cisco Global Site Selector. If site 1 goes down all site 1 traffic will be direct to site 2. If a user from site 1 travels to site 2 or 3 they should be able to access information entered. All data should be exactly the same across all data centers, in near real-time. We should also be able to easily add a new data center.

***The issue:*** I have an existing database that needs to be replicated to all 3 sites and have the exact same data. I thought I could use SQL 2008 peer-to-peer replication but that is a no go due to this method not supporting Identity columns.

What other replication technologies exist to keep 3+ SQL Server 2008 Databases in sync across global data centers? 3rd party tools? Block Replication? Remote Clustering?

Answer (score 1):

I have used Merge Replication for this purpose with good results.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151329.aspx

The largest system we ever managed like this was 11 separate locations having their on on-site server.

Note that we used this for individual locations that accessed a shared DB so that if the lines ever went down they could still operate as well.
How well this translates to off-site data centers I don't know.

We set the autonumber increment to 100 and then set the seed value for each location differently.